# How to ensure content takes full width and stays centered in landscape pdf created from html page using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

I am trying to make pdf from html page and some section will be shown in landscape orientation and some pages will be shown in portrait view. Portrait view is working fine but in landscape view contents are not taking full width. I will use puppeteer for generating pdf. Below is an example of code I am trying:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @media print {
        @page {
          size: A4;
        }

        @page landscape {
          size: A3 landscape; /* here page can be A4 or A3 depending on some business logic */
        }

        .landscape {
          page: landscape;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Portrait page.</h1>
      <p>
        Tenderloin ham boudin tongue sausage venison short ribs sirloin,
        kielbasa beef ribs. Strip steak shank bresaola salami spare ribs
        kielbasa fatback, cow t-bone flank leberkas sirloin. Jowl pork belly
        ribeye, corned beef sirloin chicken salami tail. Rump swine ham shank
        corned beef short loin, speck turkey pancetta shankle frankfurter.
        Pancetta tail fatback, ground round brisket biltong frankfurter turkey.
        Ham hock chicken strip steak, salami short ribs beef ribs pork sirloin
        pastrami pork loin turducken rump brisket andouille.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="landscape">
      <h1>Landscape page.</h1>
      <p>
        Tenderloin ham boudin tongue sausage venison short ribs sirloin,
        kielbasa beef ribs. Strip steak shank bresaola salami spare ribs
        kielbasa fatback, cow t-bone flank leberkas sirloin. Jowl pork belly
        ribeye, corned beef sirloin chicken salami tail. Rump swine ham shank
        corned beef short loin, speck turkey pancetta shankle frankfurter.
        Pancetta tail fatback, ground round brisket biltong frankfurter turkey.
        Ham hock chicken strip steak, salami short ribs beef ribs pork sirloin
        pastrami pork loin turducken rump brisket andouille.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Portrait page again.</h1>
      <p>
        Tenderloin ham boudin tongue sausage venison short ribs sirloin,
        kielbasa beef ribs. Strip steak shank bresaola salami spare ribs
        kielbasa fatback, cow t-bone flank leberkas sirloin. Jowl pork belly
        ribeye, corned beef sirloin chicken salami tail. Rump swine ham shank
        corned beef short loin, speck turkey pancetta shankle frankfurter.
        Pancetta tail fatback, ground round brisket biltong frankfurter turkey.
        Ham hock chicken strip steak, salami short ribs beef ribs pork sirloin
        pastrami pork loin turducken rump brisket andouille.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above is an example code I tried but not working. I am expecting content will also take full width in landscape mode and also content should stay in centre.

Comment: @KJ Thank you so much for your feedback. I have tried setting up hard coded width but in that case content's getting cut off.

Comment: Here you can see in the screenshot: https://ibb.co/r76XBnc